# I get a certificate error when browsing to /certsrv/ while trusted root cert is installed

Tags: certificate-authority

I have a microsoft development environment;

1. installed a windows active directory on server 2016.
2. added the microsoft certificate authority role.
3. added a setting to the default domain policy to deploy the root certificate of my newly created CA to all domain members.
4. checked with a few domain members, to see if the root certificate indeed is installed via the GPO, and it does get installed in the thrusted root
   certifices. (only wierd thing, it see it twice...)

But to my amazement, when I start the browser on one of the domain joined computers (thus equiped with the CA root certificate), and to go to my certificate authority server (also my DC), to the /certsrv/ I get a certificate error...

What am I missing here...

Comment: You made a big mistake by combining CA with DC role on the same server. I would recommend to split them to different servers. BTW, why do you need certsrv web sever?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out why; for some wierd reason, one of the configuration wizards binded the root certificate to the IIS. When I changed this to the server certificate, and used a GPO to also deploy the server certificate, things started to get working.